# Set locale for current request in Java web app

Tags: java, servlets, locale

In my Java web app, I would like to set the locale for the current request and make it available throughout the app for the duration of the request. This means that the locale is available regardless what class or method the code is in. I also don't want to retrieve the locale from the client's browser. It's retrieved from an internal database.

The Locale.setDefault cannot be used because it applies to all requests. The locale has to be set for each client request depending on the locale stored for the client issuing the request.

A singleton wouldn't work either because that would make it the same for all requests.

One solution is to simply retrieve the locale when the doGet or doPost is called and pass it around from one method to another. But that is really ugly.

A better solution would be if there is a way to attach the locale to the current request object and somehow be able to access that instance of the request object anywhere within the app. I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three way you can achieve this

1. Add a locale as a request attribute and pass the request around to your methods. Not a nice design but it will work
2. If you are using spring then you can define a @RequestScoped bean and assign the value there. A new bean instance will be created per request https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html
3. Use `ThreadLocal`. Whatever you assign will be limited and valid for a particular thread (request). Be sure to cleanup. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: I like the third approach. But if I spawn any threads within a request, I will have to either create another ThreadLocal (a duplicate), or if possible, reference the original ThreadLocal. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: If you are spawning threads then you will need to pass the info to the thread.